# WPF - Flahing button with a icon on it

Tags: wpf-controls

How do I place two icons on a WPF button, one in the middle (static icon) and one on the top left (based on a condition)? Also need to Flash the same WPF Button based on a condition?
(While flasing it switches between two background colors, the icons remains same).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone will want to help you develop super annoying flashing advertising ad style buttons :)

But to point you in the right direction the answer is in learning how to override default control template for the button then for flashing - work on Animation. Once you try that and encounter problems, then post your code and someone will help.

P.S. 'Adam Nathan's WPF Unleashed' is a good start. Good luck!